# show items per page with will paginate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have used the rails will paginate gem for pagination.I have a drop down which allows users to select number of items per page. I want my pagination to show that much items per page.

For this I am calling a jquery from my view file with change action on the select tag.

View code:

```
%table.treeTable
 %tbody
    - Ic.make_tree(@ics).values.each do |root|
      %tr{:id => root.tree_id, :class => "root"}
        %td= root.root_name
        - if show_check_boxes
          %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", root.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
      - root.suites.each do |suite|
        %tr{:id => suite.tree_id, :class => "child-of-#{root.tree_id}"}
          %td= suite.suite_name
          - if show_check_boxes
            %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", suite.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
        - suite.children.each do |case_item|
          %tr{:id => case_item.tree_id, :class => "child-of-#{suite.tree_id}"}
            %td= case_item.case_name
            - if show_check_boxes
              %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", case_item.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
          - case_item.children.each do |ic|
            %tr{:id => ic.id, :class => "child-of-#{case_item.tree_id}"}
              %td= link_to ic.name, edit_ic_path(ic.id)
              - if show_check_boxes
                %td= check_box_tag "ic_ids[]", ic.id, false
  =will_paginate @ics
```

Ajax code:

```
$('.ics_per_page').live('change',function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")); }});
  value1=($(this).val());
  $.post('/ics/index', {ics_per_page:value1});
  return false;
  })
```

From the ajax I am calling the index controller. The control goes inside the controller, but the reload is not happening.

Controller code:

```
def index
   ics_per_page=params[:ics_per_page]||5
   ics_per_page=ics_per_page.to_i
   @ics = Ic.search(params[:root_name],params[:suite_name],params[:case_name],params[:name],'f').paginate(:per_page =>ics_per_page, :page => params[:all_ics])
   respond_to do |format|
      puts "inside index"
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @ics }
    end
  end
```

Please help me out here.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't see any respond_to format.js. You are sending the AJAX request but are not using the response to manipulate the page

Comment: Hi I have no clue/idea how to implement this.so code/example help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so basically: XHR request -> controller -> action -> rendered view as return value.

You need to call your controller. This is what you do already.

Second, the data retrieved by the controller should be used to update the current page. For this, I would extend your respond_to with:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Means that JS requests will render an index.js.{erb,rjs,...} handler. In this, you write your code to update the view. The rendered output is what you are going to receive as return value in your javascript.

Last, you need to evaluate the response.

Hint: You are calling your index action via javascript. You should do this with GET and not with POST.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall try doing this.Pls let me know if my .js.erb will look like this. $('#ics_per_page').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '_listing') %>" ). Assuming I am having the view code in a partial_listing.html.haml. Please let me know if there are  any other modifications to be done

Comment: Pls let me know if my .js.erb will look like this. $('#ics_per_page').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '_listing') %>" ). Assuming I am having the view code in a partial_listing.html.haml. Please let me know if there are any other modifications to be done

Comment: ramya this could be correct, yes. now you need to evaluate it. e.g. $('#container').replace([the return value from your XHR call]).

Comment: yuo are sending data via XHR to your index action. The index action returns some data. you are AFAIK not processing this data. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and add the `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` param to your `$.post` call.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests won't reload a page. Have an invisible form in the page and submit it in the background on change of value.

Have an invisible form in the page.

```
<form action="/ics" method="get" style="display:none" id="change_number_of_ics">
  <input type="hidden" name="ics_per_page" id="num_of_items" value="" />
</form>
```

Write a jquery callback like

```
$('.ics_per_page').live('change',function(){
  value1= $(this).val();
  $("#num_of_items").attr("value", value1);
  $("form#change_number_of_ics").submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi Anannd, on chnaging the value of the drop down the form submit is not callign the index action

Comment: checkout form's action attribute. You may have to change that value according to your application routes. May be its just `/ics` instead of `/ics/index`.